# Confused about PCI slots

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer, pci

In a few months time, I am looking to buy a gaming PC,  a proper one, for the first time (I have previously had a laptop).

I have seen a pc with an MSI 970A-G43 motherboard. I was a bit stuck when it came to getting a wifi card (I know that cable is better but my room has no ethernet plugs). I believe the pc does not come with one, and am I right to believe that wireless cards need a PCI slot???

If so, will I have enough PCI slots for a wireless card, graphics card, HDD and SSD, sound card and optical drive on this particular motherboard. If so, what cards should I look to get (PCI, PCIe etc...) because the msi website is too confusing for me ^_^

Thank you!

Comment: Your question reflects a lack of a massive amount of basic information needed to spec out and build a PC from parts. You need to read articles on building PCs, not ask specific questions.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't explaining correctly but I will not build this pc, but buy it and then add a wireless card.

Comment: Then check the specs for the PC to see what available slots it will have. You can also get a USB wireless adapter.

Comment: I have tried to look at the specs of the motherboard and it says 6 but I don't know if any of them would already have been used so there would be no space for the wireless card

Comment: I have tried to look at the specs of the motherboard and it says 6 but I don't know if any of them would already have been used so there would be no space for the wireless card

Comment: GPUs effectively do not come in PCI due to the extremely limitations of that standard.  PCI and PCI-E have nearly nothing in common with one another except well the name.  HDDs are not connected on the PCI-E bus, nor are SSD, unless your dealing with M.2 drives.

Comment: Bit of a tip if you're inexperienced in building systems. Go look at the [logical increments guide](http://www.logicalincrements.com/)  and use that as a starting point based on your budget. Load that into pc parts picker, and start tweaking - it'll warn you if parts are incompatible. I've built systems for almost the last 20 years, and I find these things invaluble when trying to help folk design systems and understand what they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optical drives, HDD, and SSD typically use a SATA connection, so you shouldn't see any issues with the number of PCIe Slots on your motherboard. You don't necessarily have to get a PCI Wireless adapter either, you can also get a USB 3.0 wireless adapter too, should still give you plenty of speed on your network.

I'd recommend learning a lot more about computers before you start to get the parts for one. Try YouTube, specifically linustechtips (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw) that link should take you to his channel.

I also don't recommend that Mother Board as it still uses DDR3 which is quickly being replaced with DDR4 memory. But that is up to you.

All being said, you will have enough slots for the wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your system has one PCIe x16, 2 PCI and one PCIx1 slots. If you're using a video card, It's going to take up one PCIe x16 slot (and in most cases block a pci slot). On the bright side, a modern PC needs little else.

Your options would be to use a PCI wireless card (probably less common now) or a PCIe x1 wireless card.

In *most* cases you do *not* need a sound card on a modern PC - most modern sound cards are x1.

USB wifi varies. I keep a 802.11n/2.4 ghz nano adaptor (which is rediculously cheap) as a backup since I know it works on linux, but you can probably do better.

Finally, if you've not bought a motherboard yet, go see if you can find one with wifi built in. Its actually a pretty neat solution.